# S-57 data type in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I want to publish S-57 data format on Geoserver. Does GeoServer support S-57 and S-63 data formats? Is it possible to upload S57 directly to GeoServer without converting it to any other data format?

Comment: Do you just want to see the points / lines / areas, or are you expecting it to be rendered / symbolised like you'd see on the ECDIS?

Comment: more like ECDIS

Comment: Then you're probably going to need to do some custom styling, which you can read about in the GeoServer manual: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/index.html#styling .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never tried myself, but in theory, you should be able to read something using the [OGR community module datastore](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/ogr-store/index.html) (as a community module, you'll find a build of it only among the nightly builds).

See more about the reader capabilities in [the OGR documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/s57.html).